# O programa não está encontrando o método principal (main) da classe setup

Tags: java

Boa tarde,

Estou com problemas a correr o meu programa em Java, quando compilo não há problema, mas quando tento correr, diz que não consegue encontrar a main(String[]),

(a classe e o ficheiro têm o mesmo nome)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
//Bibliotecas
import java.awt.;
import java.awt.event.;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;
```

class setup extends Object{

```
private String jogador1;
private String jogador2;
private int pontos1;
private int pontos2;
```

public void setjogador1(String x){this.jogador1 = x;}
public void setjogador2(String x){this.jogador2 = x;}
public void setpontos1(int x){this.pontos1 = x;}
public void setpontos2(int x){this.pontos2 = x;}

public String getjogador1(){return jogador1;}
public String getjogador2(){return jogador2;}
public int getpontos1(){return pontos1;}
public int getpontos2(){return pontos2;}
}

public class jogo_prisioneiro extends Frame implements ActionListener

{
    //Dados Globais

`//setup jogador1 = new setup();
//setup jogador2 = new setup();

static setup j = new setup();
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


//Constantes
public static final int WINPOINTS = 10;
public static final int ENDGAMEDISABLEDBUTTONS = 16;
public static final String STRINGFORMAT = "%-10s %-7s %-10s %-7s\n";


String mitem1[]= {"Setup", "Jogar", "Listar", "Gráficos","-", "Abandonar"};
String mitem2[]= {"Programa", "Linguagem","-", "Autor"};
MenuBar barra;
Menu menu, menu2;
MenuItem item1[] = new MenuItem[mitem1.length];
MenuItem item2[] = new MenuItem[mitem2.length];


String st[] = {"lb0","lb1","lb2","I","lb4","lb5","lb6","lb7","lb8","II","III","IV","lb12","lb13","lb14","V","VI","VII","VIII",
"IX","lb20","X","XI","XII", "XIII", "XIV", "XV","XVI"};
Button but[] = new Button[st.length];

String st_bot[] = {"Começar 1", "Acabar 1", "Começar 2", "Acabar 2", "Abandonar"};
Button but_bot[] = new Button[st_bot.length];

Panel meio, sul;
Label lb;
Font fonte = new Font("TimesRoman", Font.BOLD, 22);
Font fonte2 = new Font("TimesRoman", Font.BOLD, 50);
Graphics stats;
int playerFirstButtonIndex = -1;
boolean firstGame = true;

int player;
int starterPlayer;
boolean isPlaying;
TextArea ta;
int numOfGames;
int desactivatedButtons;

public jogo_prisioneiro() {

    super("Jogo Prisioneiro");

    meio = novopanelcentro(but, st, fonte2, Color.blue, Color.green);
    add(meio,BorderLayout.CENTER);

    sul = novopanelsul(but_bot, st_bot, fonte, Color.blue, Color.green);
    add(sul,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    barra = criamenu(menu, "File", item1, mitem1,
                     menu2, "About", item2, mitem2);

    isPlaying = false;
    numOfGames = 0;
    ta = new TextArea(10,50);
    ta.setFont(new Font("monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    String string1 = String.format(STRINGFORMAT, "Jogador 1", "Pontos", "Jogador 2", "Pontos");
    ta.append(string1);

    Random ale = new Random();
    starterPlayer = ale.nextInt(2);

    setMenuBar(barra);



    setResizable(false);
    setSize(1280, 720);
    setVisible(true);

}

public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){



        if (e.getSource() == item1[0]){
            //int opcao = CriarDialogoEntrada("\n\tNome Jogador 1: ", "Dialogo Setup", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);



            j.setjogador1(CriarDialogoEntrada("\n\tNome jogador 1: ", "Dialogo Setup", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE));
            System.out.printf("%s\n",j.getjogador1());
            j.setjogador2(CriarDialogoEntrada("\n\tNome jogador 2: ", "Dialogo Setup", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE));
            System.out.printf("%s\n",j.getjogador2());
             item1[1].setEnabled(true);
             item1[2].setEnabled(true);
             item1[3].setEnabled(true);
        }

        if (e.getSource() == item1[1]){
                newGame();
        }

        if(e.getSource() == item1[2]){

                CriaDialogoListagem1(ta, "Listagem", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

        }


        if (e.getSource() == item1[5]) {
            int opcao = CriarDialogoConfirmacao("\n\tConfirma que quer sair\nSair da aplicacao\n","Dialogo abandonar",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
            if (opcao == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
                System.gc();
                System.exit(0);
                }//if

        }//it5

        if (e.getSource() == item2[0]) {
                     CriaDialogoSaida("\n\tJogo : Jogo do Prisioneiro\n\tVersao : 1.0\n\tData : 14-03-2017\n\tProjecto: Jogo do Prisioneiro\n\tUFCD : 5117","Dialogo do Programa",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }//end

        if (e.getSource() == item2[1]) {
                        CriaDialogoSaida("\n\tLinguagem : Java\n\tVersão : 8.0X\n\tSoftware House : Oracle Corporation\n\tLema : Write Once Run Anywahere","Diálogo Linguagem ",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }//end

        if (e.getSource() == item2[3]) {
                        CriaDialogoSaida("\n\tNome: Trainee\n\tFuncao : Java training\n\tMaxima: Makes things easy","Diálogo Autor",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

        }//end


        if(e.getSource() == but_bot[0])
        {
            int ct;
            String output = j.getjogador1();

            CriaDialogoSaida("A jogar: " +output,"Dialogo",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

            but_bot[0].setEnabled(false);
            but_bot[1].setEnabled(true);

            isPlaying = true;
            player = 1;
                    }

        if(e.getSource() == but_bot[1])
        {
            int ct;
            String output = j.getjogador2();

            CriaDialogoSaida("A jogar: " +output,"Dialogo",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

            but_bot[1].setEnabled(false);
            but_bot[2].setEnabled(true);

            playerFirstButtonIndex = -1;

            isPlaying = false;
        }


        if(e.getSource() == but_bot[2])
        {
            int ct;
            String output = j.getjogador2();
            CriaDialogoSaida("A jogar: " +output,"Dialogo",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);


            but_bot[2].setEnabled(false);
            but_bot[3].setEnabled(true);

            isPlaying = true;
            player = 2;
        }

        if(e.getSource() == but_bot[3])
        {
            int ct;
            String output = j.getjogador1();

            CriaDialogoSaida("A jogar: " +output,"Dialogo",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

            but_bot[3].setEnabled(false);
            but_bot[0].setEnabled(true);

            playerFirstButtonIndex = -1;

            isPlaying = false;
        }


        if(e.getSource() == but_bot[4])
        {
            int opcao = CriarDialogoConfirmacao("\n\tConfirma que quer sair\nSair da aplicacao\n","Dialogo abandonar",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                            if (opcao == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
                                System.gc();
                                System.exit(0);
                }
        }


        //GAME BUTTONS EVENTS

        if(e.getSource() == but[3]) {
            clickButton(3);
        }

        if(e.getSource() == but[9]) {
            clickButton(9);
        }

        if(e.getSource() == but[10]) {
            clickButton(10);
        }

        if(e.getSource() == but[11]) {
            clickButton(11);
        }

        if(e.getSource() == but[15]) {
            clickButton(15);
        }

        if(e.getSource() == but[16]) {
            clickButton(16);
        }

        if(e.getSource() == but[17]) {
            clickButton(17);
        }

        if(e.getSource() == but[18]) {
            clickButton(18);
        }

        if(e.getSource() == but[19]) {
            clickButton(19);
        }

        if(e.getSource() == but[21]) {
            clickButton(21);
        }

        if(e.getSource() == but[22]) {
            clickButton(22);
        }

        if(e.getSource() == but[23]) {
            clickButton(23);
        }

        if(e.getSource() == but[24]) {
            clickButton(24);
        }

        if(e.getSource() == but[25]) {
            clickButton(25);
        }

        if(e.getSource() == but[26]) {
            clickButton(26);
        }

        if(e.getSource() == but[27]) {
            clickButton(27);
        }


}


// PRIVATE METHODS


/*
/ CREATE A NEW GAME
*/
private void newGame() {

    //Increase number of games
    numOfGames++;

    desactivatedButtons = 0;

    isPlaying = false;

    int oldStarter = starterPlayer;


    if(numOfGames > 1 ) {
        if(starterPlayer == 1)
            starterPlayer = 0;
        else
            starterPlayer = 1;

        CriaDialogoSaida("Jogo passado começou o jogador " + (oldStarter+1) + " este jogo começa o jogador " + (starterPlayer+1),"NOVO JOGO",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }

    resetGameButtons();

    if (starterPlayer == 0){
        but_bot[0].setEnabled(true);
        but_bot[1].setEnabled(false);
        but_bot[2].setEnabled(false);
        but_bot[3].setEnabled(false);
        but_bot[4].setEnabled(true);

    }
    else
    {
        but_bot[0].setEnabled(false);
        but_bot[1].setEnabled(false);
        but_bot[2].setEnabled(true);
        but_bot[3].setEnabled(false);
        but_bot[4].setEnabled(true);
    }


}


/*
/ RESET GAME BUTTONS
*/
private void resetGameButtons() {

    for(int ct = 0; ct < st.length; ct++) {
        playerFirstButtonIndex=-1;
        if(ct != 0 && ct != 1 && ct != 2 && ct != 4 && ct != 5 && ct != 6 && ct != 7 && ct != 8 && ct !=12 && ct != 13 && ct != 14 && ct != 20 ) {
            but[ct].setEnabled(true);
        }
    }

}

/*
/ Finish the game
*/
private void finishGame() {


    String j1 = j.getjogador1();
    String j2 = j.getjogador2();
    int p1 = j.getpontos1();
    int p2 = j.getpontos2();

    if(player == 1){
        CriaDialogoSaida("\n\tO jogador " + j2 + " ganhou", "WINNER", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        j.setpontos2(WINPOINTS);
        j.setpontos1(0);
    } else {
        CriaDialogoSaida("\n\tO jogador " + j1 +  " ganhou", "WINNER", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        j.setpontos1(WINPOINTS);
        j.setpontos2(0);
    }

    String string2 = String.format(STRINGFORMAT, j.getjogador1(), j.getpontos1(), j.getjogador2(), j.getpontos2());
    ta.append(string2);




    //DAR DISABLE AOS BUTOES

    for(int y=0; y < st_bot.length - 1; y++){
        but_bot[y].setEnabled(false);


    }
}

/*
/ Check if the game is finished (if the disabled buttons is equal to ENDGAMEDISABLEDBUTTONS)
*/
private boolean checkEndGame() {
    if(desactivatedButtons == ENDGAMEDISABLEDBUTTONS)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}





/*
/ CLICK A SPECIFIC GAME BUTTON (buttonIndex)
*/
private void clickButton(int buttonIndex) {

    if(!isPlaying) {
        CriaDialogoSaida("\n\tTens que começar a tua jogada", "CHECKLINE", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        return ;
    }


    if(playerFirstButtonIndex != -1) {
        checkLine(buttonIndex, playerFirstButtonIndex);
    } else {
        //TODO: DISABLE BUTTON
        but[buttonIndex].setEnabled(false);
        playerFirstButtonIndex = buttonIndex;
        desactivatedButtons++;
    }

    if(checkEndGame()) {
        finishGame();
    }

}

/*
/ CHECK IF THE PLAYER CAN DESACTIVATE THE BUTTON
*/
private void checkLine(int actualButtonIndex, int firstButtonIndex) {

        boolean canDesactivate = true;

        if( (firstButtonIndex == 3 && actualButtonIndex != 3) ||
            ( (firstButtonIndex >=9 && firstButtonIndex <= 11) && (actualButtonIndex < 9 || actualButtonIndex > 11) ) ||
            ( (14 < firstButtonIndex && firstButtonIndex < 20) && (actualButtonIndex <= 14 || actualButtonIndex >= 20) ) ||
            ( (20 < firstButtonIndex && firstButtonIndex < 28) && (actualButtonIndex <= 20 || actualButtonIndex >= 28) ))
        {

                CriaDialogoSaida("\n\tNão podes mudar de linha", "CHECKLINE", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        } else {
            but[actualButtonIndex].setEnabled(false);
            desactivatedButtons++;
        }
}

public void graph(Graphics gra) {

    gra.setColor(Color.red);
    gra.fillOval(330-5,220-5,10,10);

}






private Panel novopanelcentro(Button bt[], String sr[], Font font, Color cor, Color cor2){

    int ct;
    Panel mid;

    mid = new Panel(new GridLayout(4,7,10,5));

            for (ct=0; ct<but.length; ct++)
            {

                    if(ct == 0 || ct == 1 || ct == 2 || ct == 4 || ct == 5 || ct == 6 || ct == 7 || ct == 8 || ct ==12 || ct == 13 || ct == 14 || ct == 20 )
                    {
                    lb = new Label(" ");
                    mid.add(lb);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    bt[ct] = new Button(sr[ct]);
                    bt[ct].setFont(font);
                    bt[ct].setBackground(cor);
                    bt[ct].setForeground(cor2);
                    bt[ct].setEnabled(false);
                    bt[ct].addActionListener(this);
                    mid.add(bt[ct]);
                    }
    }
    return mid;
}

private Panel novopanelsul (Button bt[], String sr[], Font font, Color cor, Color cor2){

    int ct;
    Panel bot;

    bot = new Panel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER,25,10));

    for (ct=0; ct<but_bot.length; ct++){
        bt[ct] = new Button(sr[ct]);
        bt[ct].setFont(font);
        bt[ct].setBackground(cor);
        bt[ct].setForeground(cor2);
        bt[ct].setEnabled(false);
        bt[ct].addActionListener(this);
        bot.add(bt[ct]);

        }

    return bot;
}


private MenuBar criamenu (Menu mu1, String st1, MenuItem mi1[], String dados1[], Menu mu2, String st2, MenuItem mi2[], String dados2[]){

    MenuBar mbarra1;
    int ct;


    mbarra1 = new MenuBar();

    mu1 = new Menu(st1);

    for (ct=0;ct<dados1.length;ct++){
            mi1[ct]= new MenuItem(dados1[ct]);
            mi1[ct].addActionListener(this);
            mu1.add(mi1[ct]);
            }

        mbarra1.add(mu1);
        mi1[1].setEnabled(false);
        mi1[2].setEnabled(false);
        mi1[3].setEnabled(false);

    mu2 = new Menu(st2);

    for (ct=0;ct<dados2.length;ct++){
            mi2[ct]= new MenuItem(dados2[ct]);
            mi2[ct].addActionListener(this);
            mu2.add(mi2[ct]);
            }

        mbarra1.add(mu2);


return mbarra1;
}


private int CriarDialogoConfirmacao(String ms, String t, int i) {
        int devolve = 0;
        devolve = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
            ms,
            t,
            i);
        return devolve;

}


private void CriaDialogoSaida(String ms, String t, int i) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ms, t, i);
            ;

    }

private String CriarDialogoEntrada(String ms, String t, int i)
{
    String devolve = "";
    devolve = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, ms, t, i);
    return devolve;

}

private void CriaDialogoListagem1(TextArea text, String ms, int i) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,text,ms,i);
}




//MAIN


public static void main (String[] args){
    jogo_prisioneiro app = new jogo_prisioneiro();


    app.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
                        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
                        System.gc();
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                });
    }
}`

Alguém pode me dizer o que à de errado?

Comment: extends object é inutil. Toda classe de java ja estende Object obrigatoriamente, msm q vc nunca defina, isso é regra de funcionamento do java.

Answer (score 0):

**Há erros de sintaxe no seu código, portanto, considere as seguinte alterações para que ele seja executado:**

> Altere:

```
import java.awt.;
import java.awt.event.;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;
```

> Para:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;
```

---

> E, também, de:

`public class jogo_prisioneiro extends Frame implements ActionListener {`

> Para

`class jogo_prisioneiro extends Frame implements`

---

> **É pra aparecer esta tela?**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Sim é para aparecer isso, eu alterei o que você disse mas mesmo assim não funcionou